# How to insert multiple rows in MS SQL from a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table called InputTable with the following elements:

```
CaseID    Note1    Note2    UpdatedBy    UpdatedDate
```

I need to copy the data from InputTable into a second table (called OutputTable) that has the following elements:

```
CaseKey   Note   LastModifiedBy   LastModifiedDate
```

My current script looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO OutputTable (CaseKey, Note, LastModifiedBy, LastModifiedDate)
SELECT CaseID, Note1, UpdatedBy, UpdatedDate
FROM InputTable
```

How can I modify the script so it will write 2 records to OutputTable?  The first record should pick up InputTable.CaseID, InputTable.Note1, InputTable.UpdatedBy, and InputTable.UpdatedDate and the second record should pick up InputTable.CaseID, InputTable.Note2, InputTable.UpdatedBy, and InputTable.UpdatedDate.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't run too many INSERT statements, but can you UNION ALL (or UNION) two select queries? In the 2nd query, just change Note1 to Note2 and maybe require Note2 is not null.

Comment: write a trigger that will insert automatically only the new cases

Comment: Union is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a cross apply:

```sql
INSERT INTO OutputTable (CaseKey, Note, LastModifiedBy, LastModifiedDate)
SELECT CaseID, x.note, UpdatedBy, UpdatedDate
FROM InputTable i
cross apply (
  select Note1 AS note
  union all
  select Note2
) x
```

This creates two rows from one with Note1 and Note2 as the only difference.

If you want to supress duplicate Note1 and Note2, you can change UNION ALL to just UNION or change select Note2 to select Note2 WHERE Note2 <> Note1